# JQuery Hacer JetSmartFilters Toggle para elemento Radio Button

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

hoy estoy atascado con un pequeña modificación que no trae el Pluging de Crocoblock Jet Smart Filters.  Tengo un conjunto de categorías de productos y he construido un filtro con Jet Smart Filters del tipo Radio Button.  Lo que necesito es colapsar todas las categorias por su elemento padre ya que hay categorias y subcategorías, y colocar un Toggle tipo "+" para indicar que se expande que al hacer clic expanda ese ítem del árbol construido y cambie a "-".

He conseguido alguna docu aqui: https://element.how/crocoblock-jetsmartfilters-toggle/  y he realizado la siguiente prueba la que me arroga un error ya que no se muestra el "-" cuando esta expandido el elemento y esta abriendo / expandiendo todas las categorias "padres" que tengan hijos.

Yo necesito poder presentar el árbol con todas las categorias padres colapsadas ya que son muchas y que se expanda cuando se hace clic en una y se contraiga/colapse las que no esten activas.

Mi código:

```
<style>
    .jet-list-tree__parent:after{
        content: "+";/* modify this to change the down arrow icon */
        float: right;
        margin-right: 10px;   
    }
    .jet-list-tree__children.noicon:after{
        content: "";
    }
    .jet-list-tree__children {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .jet-list-tree__children.noicon {
        cursor: default;
    }
    
    .jet-list-tree__parent.minus{
        content: "-";
    }
    </style>
    
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            jQuery(function($){
                    $('.jet-list-tree__parent').slice(0,1).slideDown();
                    $('.jet-list-tree__children').slice(0,1).addClass('noicon');
                    $('.jet-list-tree__parent').click(function(){
                        $(this).next().slideToggle().addClass('minus');
                    });
                    
            });
        });
    </script>
```

El código original del template  construido por woocommerce es el siguiente:

```
<div class="jet-list-tree__children noicon minus" style="">
<div class="jet-radio-list__row jet-filter-row jet-list-tree__parent">
    <label class="jet-radio-list__item">
        <input type="radio" class="jet-radio-list__input" name="product_cat" value="1685" data-label="Accesorios para Piscina">
        <div class="jet-radio-list__button">
                            <span class="jet-radio-list__decorator"><i class="jet-radio-list__checked-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
                        <span class="jet-radio-list__label">Accesorios para Piscina</span>
            <span class="jet-filters-counter"><span class="counter-prefix">(</span><span class="value">7</span><span class="counter-suffix">)</span></span>     </div>
    </label>
</div>  <div class="jet-list-tree__children minus" style="">
<div class="jet-radio-list__row jet-filter-row">
    <label class="jet-radio-list__item">
        <input type="radio" class="jet-radio-list__input" name="product_cat" value="1686" data-label="Boyas">
        <div class="jet-radio-list__button">
                            <span class="jet-radio-list__decorator"><i class="jet-radio-list__checked-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
                        <span class="jet-radio-list__label">Boyas</span>
            <span class="jet-filters-counter"><span class="counter-prefix">(</span><span class="value">2</span><span class="counter-suffix">)</span></span>     </div>
    </label>
</div><div class="jet-radio-list__row jet-filter-row">
    <label class="jet-radio-list__item">
        <input type="radio" class="jet-radio-list__input" name="product_cat" value="1843" data-label="Cascadas">
        <div class="jet-radio-list__button">
                            <span class="jet-radio-list__decorator"><i class="jet-radio-list__checked-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
                        <span class="jet-radio-list__label">Cascadas</span>
            <span class="jet-filters-counter"><span class="counter-prefix">(</span><span class="value">4</span><span class="counter-suffix">)</span></span>     </div>
    </label>
</div><div class="jet-radio-list__row jet-filter-row">
    <label class="jet-radio-list__item">
        <input type="radio" class="jet-radio-list__input" name="product_cat" value="1687" data-label="Pastilla de Cloro">
        <div class="jet-radio-list__button">
                            <span class="jet-radio-list__decorator"><i class="jet-radio-list__checked-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
                        <span class="jet-radio-list__label">Pastilla de Cloro</span>
            <span class="jet-filters-counter"><span class="counter-prefix">(</span><span class="value">1</span><span class="counter-suffix">)</span></span>     </div>
    </label>
</div>  </div>
```

No se que mas hacer.  Help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
/*  recorres todo los padres de tu componenete con each()  */
    $('.jet-list-tree__children').each(function( index ) {
       $(this).children('.jet-radio-list__row').each( function( index ) {
           // Aquí puedes recorrer los hijos de cada padre
           
            var radio_input_activated = $(this)
           .children('.jet-radio-list__item')
           .children('.jet-radio-list__input');

           if( radio_input_activated.is(':checked') ) {
               
              /* En este punto el check del radio esta activo y manipulas lo demás en el árbol en base a si es - o si es +  */

           }
       })
    })
```

Comment: Gracias Nelson, pero no me funciono.

Comment: Te explico el código, primero recorres los elementos $('.jet-list-tree__children'), cada uno puede tener dentro 1>=elementos, ósea que habría que dentro de cada uno de los elementos $('.jet-list-tree__children') pueden haber múltiples elementos $('.jet-radio-list__row'), dentro de estos es donde están tus radio buttons, en base a los mismo puedes tomar tus decisiones de si esta encendido + o si esta apagado -, lo cual hace el condicional if() dentro del código que te di arriba